# Stop getting same result twice in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I'm doing a microblogging site (like Twitter) using a mySQL database. In that database I have three tables: one for users, one for messages and one to control who follows who. When the user enters the site I want to show his own messages and those from the people who he follows, so I use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM messages 
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = messages.author 
INNER JOIN followers ON followers.main_user = 2 
WHERE messages.author = followers.followed_user OR messages.author = 2 
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Being '2' the user that's entering the site.

The thing is that I get the messages written by the person who enters (2, in this example) twice, and once from the people he follows. Does anyone have a clue about how to solve this? User 2 doesn't follow himself.

Comment: What if a user follows no one? This query would return `0` rows then.

Comment: Exactly, or even if a person follows people who hasn't written yet. In that case, I control it with JSP telling him that there are no messages to show.

Comment: so isn't that obvious for you then that you need to select own messages and followings messages separately? "I control it with JSP telling him that there are no messages to show." --- "I want to show **his own messages** and those from the people who he follows" - my point was that you won't even show own messages

Comment: If I do it separately then I can't order them by date (or at least I don't know how to do it, any suggestion?). 

The query works, but I get my own messages twice, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: "The query works, but I get my own messages twice, which doesn't make sense." --- if it **works** - what your question is about? What doesn't make sense is the query, not its results - which is perfectly expected. Have 2 separated queries. If you want their results combined - use `UNION`

Comment: It doesn't work **properly** because I get my own messages **twice** and I only want them **once**, and my question was **why is that happening**. 

I have used this query now to do it separately, as you say:

SELECT users.username, users.name, users.surname, messages.content, messages.date, messages.author, messages.id, messages.yours FROM messages INNER JOIN users ON users.id = messages.author INNER JOIN followers ON followers.main_user = 2 WHERE messages.author = 2 ORDER BY date DESC";

I still get them twice, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "I still get them twice" --- here you're not selecting your own messages. How you could *still* get *them* (own messages) twice? There must be no your messages at all. You are not joining `followers` and `users` table, so you're getting cartesian product

Comment: 'WHERE messages.author = 2' means I'm selecting my own messages since i'm user number 2.

Comment: it does, but you don't have join condition for   `followers` table with either `messages` or `users` table

Comment: Ok, it's solved already. Thanks anyway.